# more than one device/emulator - Error while trying to cast with Genymobile

Tags: android, android-studio

I have attached a device and emulator.
When I'm trying to cast screen with Genymobile I'm getting:

> INFO: scrcpy 1.10 https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy adb: error: failed to get feature set: more than one device/emulator

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Refer to the link: https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy/issues/185#issuecomment-405929700

1. Find the device/emulator identifier with `adb devices`
2. Cast in the Genymobile with `scrcpy -s YOUR_DEVICE_COD`

Answer (score 0):

I tryed scrcpy on latest linux mint xfce distribution

I connected my android 10 smartphone via USB cable, started scrcpy from shell and got a similar error message.

I read somewhere that USB DEBUGGING should be enabled on my android smartphone.

So I enabled developer mode in my phone, enabled USB DEBUGGING and the connected my phone to pc.

Started strcpy and everything was alright